# Getting row count with other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to get some columns which are `LinkID`, `ReplyCount` and the most important one is `TotalRowCount`.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
   TOP(10) link.LinkID, mesaj.ReplyCount
FROM 
   TBL_UserIcerikler AS link 
INNER JOIN 
   TBL_UserMesajlar AS mesaj  ON link.FromUserID = mesaj.UserID
WHERE 
   link.PublishDate >='2013-03-12 19:46:45.000' 
ORDER BY
   link.PublishDate DESC
```

It is not running anymore when I add `Count(*) AS a`".

I get this message instead. How can I get row count? Does anyone have any information about this topic?

> *Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Invalid object name 'TBL_UserIcerikler'*

Answer (score 1):

`Count(*)` is an aggregate function which returns the number of rows which have been summarised (not the number of rows returned by the query), so you must `GROUP BY` something and specify only the fields by which you group (or just return COUNT(*)).

It doesn't make a lot of sense to mix COUNT() and TOP().

For example :

```
SELECT link.LinkID, mesaj.ReplyCount, COUNT(*)
  FROM TBL_UserIcerikler AS link 
  INNER JOIN TBL_UserMesajlar AS mesaj ON link.FromUserID = mesaj.UserID
  WHERE link.PublishDate >='2013-03-12 19:46:45.000'
  GROUP BY link.LinkID, mesaj.ReplyCount;
```

I know it's not quite what you want, but you haven't given quite enough explanation as to what you want to get out of your database.

That said, I think you might have forgotten a comma in the expression list.

Why not post your modified query.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said. :) Can you explain it more.

Comment: I got this mesagge when I ran your example code Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'TBL_UserIcerikler'.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my computer. It's not just that you've misspelled the table name ? Can you edit your question and add the table definitions (SCRIPT TABLE AS CREATE... in SQL Management Studio) ?

Comment: Because it's the normal way to use COUNT(*).

Comment: But when I do the same what you said, I can't use ROW_NUMBER(). Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'TBL_UserIcerikler.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you with the table definitions and a statement of what you want to get out of your query. http://sqlfiddle.com is a super way to share database problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) MSDN explanation of group by, you will understand why you need it to get your total count.